# extend from x to y

Tags: paraphrasing

I need to paraphrase "Mesoamerican gene pool extends from Mexico to Colombia", but could not find a better one with my current vocabulary.

Can anybody help please? It is going to be in a scientific paper.

Comment: What's wrong with it as it is?

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=kbx_0HBr9sYC&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=%22gene+pool+extends%22&source=bl&ots=PFanclzKtQ&sig=NPpgLTTbV_pvxaN7D61Y7-g-Ej0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9o9rO14jcAhXypVkKHUNjC9AQ6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=%22gene%20pool%20extends%22&f=false

Comment: There is nothing wrong, but this is pure information and I need to paraphrase as I need to avoid plagiarism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“The Mesoamerican gene pool is predominantly found from Colombia up to Mexico.”

“Predominantly” means “mostly”.